# Object data not updating when database entry changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My website has a banner that displays messages to visitors for emergency/special situations.  The banner displays based on a call to a database table which checks for start/finish times against a DateTime.Now object.

`static private PublicWebEntities db = new PublicWebEntities();
        public IEnumerable<AlertMsg> CurrentAlert()
        {
            var alerts = from q in db.AlertMsgs where (q.Start < DateTime.Now && q.Finish > DateTime.Now) select q;
            return alerts;
        }`

and displays in the page by

```
@if (Model.CurrentAlert().Any()){           
<div class="alert-block">
    <a href="" class="button-close">X</a>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CurrentAlert())  {
        <p>
        @Html.Raw(item.Message)
        </p>  }
</div>}
```

If I change either the start or finish times in a record, the banner turns off. But when the text message of a record is updated, the display is a cached copy of the old message.

I'm using EF 4.1 and MVC3 for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the server is caching the page, you can use the `OutputCache` attribute to control hold long it would store the page for.

Using the following will "turn off" the cache:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = false, Duration = 0)]
public ActionResult Index(){
    //Your code
}
```

This should disable the action you are calling to populate the results from caching.

#### Using base controller for per session requests (brought up in comment)

An example of having the controller control the lifecycle of the context

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a base implementation for controllers using a single, simple common context
/// </summary>
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public MyDbContext Db { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        Db = new MyDbContext();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Manages saving the changes back to the database.  This should be performed per action and you shouldn't have to manage it
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Db.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()) Db.SaveChanges();

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release the resources the context uses and close connections if needed
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(Db != null) Db.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be because I am using .NET 4, but I get errors with OutputCacheLocation.Net.  Instead I'm using

`[OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam = "none")]
public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var msg = new AlertMsg();
            return View(msg);
        }
`

Comment: It's just not working. and your code comes back as "does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @techmaniac If you have the time, I would be interested in seeing the stack trace for the error message.

Comment: It doesn't even build with this error.  It's an output error in VS 2010.

Comment: What's also interesting to me is that it responds to changes in the DB of the startTime and endTime, but not the change in the text.  It's like it's just caching the string object in the EF entity, but not the datetime object.

Comment: FYI, I was missing a using statement for System.Web.UI.  That solved the original Context error I was seeing.

Comment: It still doesn't solve the message refresh issue.
If I stop debugging and restart, of course it uses the changed record, but otherwise when you refresh the page in the browser it continues to display the outdated data.\

Comment: Interesting...  Did you update the attribute to my newest edit?  The two additional parameters should definitely stop that.  You are using a static context and EF does cache the returned entities.  Have you tried using a context per http request instead of a shared static one?

Comment: I did include the newest edit, but that didn't make a difference.  Please expand on how best to use a per request approach.  I'm assuming you mean placing a context in the application start or creating a new function in that global.asax file.  Would this also be overcome by switching to the repository patter?

Comment: The DbContext is a repository.  It follows the UoW pattern and allows the queries to stay platform agnostic.  You can put it into the `BeginRequest` and `EndRequest`, IoC container, or you can create a base controller that creates the context in the ctor and when and dispose of the context in the `Dispose` method of the controller.